# Joomla 1.6 URL rewrite on IIS7 (removing /index.php/)

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting, iis7

Joomla 1.6 was released today and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to get rid of the /index.php/ part?

How link looks now:

> `http://www.example.org/index.php/stuff`

How link would look after URL rewrite:

> `http://www.example.org/stuff`

The old code (j1.5) at this link doesn't work: http://docs.joomla.org/SEO_and_IIS_ISAPI

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="base64_encode.*\(.*\)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(\&lt;|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="_REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" url="index.php" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="^/index.php" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it didn't help. I think it has to with the fact that I'm not running IIS with FastCGI. Hopefully the code will be useful for others.

Comment: Where shall I put this?
I am using Joomla 1.6

Thanks

Comment: You add the code in the URL Rewrite module in IIS7. If you don't have it installed you can add it to your IIS: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/